# Read and write file from Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 in python

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-lake-gen2

AS per Microsoft documents:

Connect to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 by using an account key:

```
def initialize_storage_account(storage_account_name, storage_account_key):
    
    try:  
        global service_client

        service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
            "https", storage_account_name), credential=storage_account_key)
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Upload a file to a directory:

```
def upload_file_to_directory():
    try:
        file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="my-file-system")

        directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client("my-directory/filter")
        
        file_client = directory_client.create_file("my_csv_write.csv")
        local_file = open("C:\\Users\\my_csv_read.csv",'r')

        file_contents = local_file.read()

        file_client.append_data(data=file_contents, offset=0, length=len(file_contents))

        file_client.flush_data(len(file_contents))
        print("File uploaded")

    except Exception as e:
      print(e)
```

I can upload file from my local to azure storage with this function, and it works.

but what I want to do is Read file from azure storage and write in azure storage.
What I did

```
def read_and_write_to_directory():
    try:
        file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="my-file-system")

        directory_client_read = file_system_client.get_directory_client("my-directory")
        directory_client_write = file_system_client.get_directory_client("my-directory/filter")

        file_client_read = directory_client_read.get_file_client("my_csv_read.csv")
        file_path = open(file_client_read,'r')
        file_contents = file_path.read()
        

        file_client_write = directory_client_write.create_file("my_csv_write.csv")
        file_client_write.append_data(file_contents, overwrite=True)
        
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

But it does not work,

error

```
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DataLakeFileClient
```

So What is the correct way to read file from azure lake storage and write in azure lake storage?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a little late, but I stumbled onto this while looking for a different issue.
I think you need to read the file content and then write that, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python#download-from-a-directory), and write it, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python#upload-a-file-to-a-directory)
So your code would look like this:

```
def read_and_write_to_directory():
try:
    file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="my-file-system")

    directory_client_read = file_system_client.get_directory_client("my-directory")
    directory_client_write = file_system_client.get_directory_client("my-directory/filter")

    file_client_read = directory_client_read.get_file_client("my_csv_read.csv")
    #file_path = open(file_client_read,'r')
    #file_contents = file_path.read()

    download = file_client_read.download_file()
    downloaded_bytes = download.readall()

    

    file_client_write = directory_client_write.create_file("my_csv_write.csv")
    #file_client_write.append_data(file_contents, overwrite=True)
    file_client_write.append_data(downloaded_bytes, overwrite=True)


except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```